# CLIPS. Create deffunction where i could delete words from text and printout results to file

Tags: clips

I have a problem.
I need to delete words from the text and to do printout to file result(Text without deleted words).

Here I'm trying to delete words:

```
(deffunction  text ($?c)
(implode$(create$ ?c ))
(delete$ (?c) 1 3)
(printout t (?c) crlf))
```

And here example to printout it to file, but how to do it with results of previous function?

```
CLIPS> (open "on.txt" data "w")
TRUE
CLIPS> (printout data 5)
CLIPS> (close data)
TRUE
CLIPS> (open "on.txt" data "r")
TRUE
CLIPS> (read data)
5
CLIPS> (close data)
```

I will be happy with whatever information.

Comment: I alredy solved it:)Here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Xll.png